# deploy a Vue+Electron application for both desktop and web application

Tags: vue.js, iis, electron, desktop-application

I have used [this template](https://github.com/mubaidr/vue-electron-template) for developing my application which is a Vue app with an Electron builder. Now I have a problem:
I need to build production and deploy my project once as an electron package and another time for a web application hosted on a web server. I do not want to separate it into two repositories as well. Do anybody have any suggestions?

I have tried using dist folder as root folder of website and I have added a web.config file as follow to the root but I am getting an error.

web.config file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Vue" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/api/.*" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

the error on IIS:
[image]

Comment: I checked web.config and there's no format error. Did you install url rewrite module in IIS?

Comment: No, I haven't installed that. Should I?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to install url rewrite module on IIS. Otherwise, IIS won't understand what `<rewrite>  <rules>  <rule name="Vue" stopProcessing="true">` means in web.config.

Download it from [here](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)